# linux from scratch

Tags: linux

is it feasible to install linux from scratch(LFS) on a host distro(suse)??...
how to make this LFS independent of platform?...
can it be made into a liveCD and be installable on systems??

Answer (score 1):

LFS is supposed to be a barebones installation, so installing it along with a host distro kind of takes the whole point out of doing it. Why not use a virtual machine on the host?

Comment: i am trying to create a new linux system while working on an existing linux OS...the question i'm asking is-can developing of LFS possible on openSUSE without any error or mistake borne within the host linux(suse)?..[refer linuxfromscratch.org]

Answer (score 0):

you can try [mondorescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/)

Comment: not at al helpful..